# Protect admin routes in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I am using this route to access the dashboard which should only be accesible when one is logged in. unfortunately any one is able to access it. What should I do? Here is my route

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'web', 'prefix'=>'backed'], function(){ Route::get('backend/dashboard', array('as'=>'dashboard', 'uses'=>'BackendDashboardController@getDashboard')); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `auth` middleware to your route group.

```
Route::group(['middleware'=> ['web', 'auth'], 'prefix'=>'backed'], function(){ Route::get('backend/dashboard', array('as'=>'dashboard', 'uses'=>'BackendDashboardController@getDashboard')); });
```

Comment: When I add the middleware auth as suggested above it redirects back to login even when I login with correct email and password

Comment: This middleware check if user not logged in and redirect on the login page. So for getting this route you should be logged in